# Query sometime not using index

Tags: mysql, performance, tokudb, query-performance

Starting in the middle of last night (of course) I have a query that stops using an index and when that happens, it takes over an hour to complete vs. about 3 seconds when it uses the index. This query has been run for more than a year with no issues until last night.

What I have been able to figure out is that the query is using an index sometimes and not others; using explain.  It has been slow for 2 hours, then fast for 1 hour and now slow again, etc.

When the query is running fast, explain tells me the query is using the key: `builder_row_id`

When it is running slow, it has no key and the Extra has: Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

Here are the 2 rows from explain, sorry about the formatting:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,e8_,,ALL,builder_row_id,,,,1,100,Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1,SIMPLE,e8_,,ref,builder_row_id,builder_row_id,6,"my_db_name.e6_.builder_block_id,const",4,100, 

SELECT
    e0_.id AS id_0,
    e0_.name AS name_1,
    e0_.content_id AS content_id_2,
    e0_.from_label AS from_label_3,
    e0_.support_address AS support_address_4,
    e0_.actual_from_label AS actual_from_label_5,
    e0_.actual_from_address AS actual_from_address_6,
    e0_.enable_wysiwyg AS enable_wysiwyg_7,
    e0_.enable_conversation AS enable_conversation_8,
    e0_.folder_id AS folder_id_9,
    e0_.enable_transactional AS enable_transactional_10,
    e0_.type_id AS type_id_11,
    e0_.utm_content AS utm_content_12,
    e1_.builder_style_id AS builder_style_id_13,
    e1_.id AS id_14,
    e1_.builder_style_key AS builder_style_key_15,
    e1_.builder_style_value AS builder_style_value_16,
    e1_.builder_style_delete_status AS builder_style_delete_status_17,
    e2_.content_id AS content_id_18,
    e2_.content_text AS content_text_19,
    e2_.content_html AS content_html_20,
    e2_.content_subject AS content_subject_21,
    e2_.content_preview_png AS content_preview_png_22,
    e3_.builder_region_id AS builder_region_id_23,
    e3_.id AS id_24,
    e3_.builder_region_name AS builder_region_name_25,
    e3_.builder_region_type_id AS builder_region_type_id_26,
    e3_.builder_region_delete_status AS builder_region_delete_status_27,
    e3_.builder_region_sort_order AS builder_region_sort_order_28,
    e3_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_29,
    e4_.builder_region_style_id AS builder_region_style_id_30,
    e4_.builder_region_id AS builder_region_id_31,
    e4_.builder_region_style_key AS builder_region_style_key_32,
    e4_.builder_region_style_value AS builder_region_style_value_33,
    e4_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_34,
    e4_.builder_region_style_delete_status AS builder_region_style_delete_status_35,
    e5_.builder_row_id AS builder_row_id_36,
    e5_.builder_region_id AS builder_region_id_37,
    e5_.builder_row_type_id AS builder_row_type_id_38,
    e5_.builder_row_delete_status AS builder_row_delete_status_39,
    e5_.builder_row_sort_order AS builder_row_sort_order_40,
    e5_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_41,
    e6_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_42,
    e6_.builder_row_id AS builder_row_id_43,
    e6_.builder_block_type_id AS builder_block_type_id_44,
    e6_.builder_block_delete_status AS builder_block_delete_status_45,
    e6_.builder_block_sort_order AS builder_block_sort_order_46,
    e6_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_47,
    e7_.builder_block_attribute_id AS builder_block_attribute_id_48,
    e7_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_49,
    e7_.builder_block_attribute_key AS builder_block_attribute_key_50,
    e7_.builder_block_attribute_value AS builder_block_attribute_value_51,
    e7_.builder_block_attribute_delete_status AS builder_block_attribute_delete_status_52,
    e8_.builder_column_id AS builder_column_id_53,
    e8_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_54,
    e8_.parent_builder_column_id AS parent_builder_column_id_55,
    e8_.builder_column_type_id AS builder_column_type_id_56,
    e8_.builder_column_delete_status AS builder_column_delete_status_57,
    e8_.builder_column_sort_order AS builder_column_sort_order_58,
    e8_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_59,
    e9_.builder_column_style_id AS builder_column_style_id_60,
    e9_.builder_column_style_key AS builder_column_style_key_61,
    e9_.builder_column_style_value AS builder_column_style_value_62,
    e9_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_63,
    e9_.builder_column_style_delete_status AS builder_column_style_delete_status_64,
    e10_.builder_column_attribute_id AS builder_column_attribute_id_65,
    e10_.builder_column_attribute_key AS builder_column_attribute_key_66,
    e10_.builder_column_attribute_value AS builder_column_attribute_value_67,
    e10_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_68,
    e10_.builder_column_attribute_delete_status AS builder_column_attribute_delete_status_69,
    e11_.builder_column_conf_id AS builder_column_conf_id_70,
    e11_.builder_column_conf_key AS builder_column_conf_key_71,
    e11_.builder_column_conf_value AS builder_column_conf_value_72,
    e11_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_73,
    e11_.builder_column_conf_delete_status AS builder_column_conf_delete_status_74,
    e12_.builder_column_id AS builder_column_id_75,
    e12_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_76,
    e12_.parent_builder_column_id AS parent_builder_column_id_77,
    e12_.builder_column_type_id AS builder_column_type_id_78,
    e12_.builder_column_delete_status AS builder_column_delete_status_79,
    e12_.builder_column_sort_order AS builder_column_sort_order_80,
    e12_.builder_ui_id AS builder_ui_id_81,
    e0_.content_id AS content_id_82,
    e0_.product_id AS product_id_83,
    e0_.unsubscribe_message_id AS unsubscribe_message_id_84,
    e0_.unsubscribe_language_id AS unsubscribe_language_id_85,
    e0_.rbac_role_id AS rbac_role_id_86,
    e0_.folder_id AS folder_id_87,
    e1_.id AS id_88,
    e3_.id AS id_89,
    e4_.builder_region_id AS builder_region_id_90,
    e5_.builder_region_id AS builder_region_id_91,
    e6_.builder_row_id AS builder_row_id_92,
    e7_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_93,
    e8_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_94,
    e8_.parent_builder_column_id AS parent_builder_column_id_95,
    e9_.builder_column_id AS builder_column_id_96,
    e10_.builder_column_id AS builder_column_id_97,
    e11_.builder_column_id AS builder_column_id_98,
    e12_.builder_block_id AS builder_block_id_99,
    e12_.parent_builder_column_id AS parent_builder_column_id_100
FROM
    email e0_
    LEFT JOIN builder_style e1_ ON e0_.id = e1_.id AND (e1_.builder_style_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN content e2_ ON e0_.content_id = e2_.content_id
    LEFT JOIN builder_region e3_ ON e0_.id = e3_.id AND (e3_.builder_region_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_region_style e4_ ON e3_.builder_region_id = e4_.builder_region_id AND (e4_.builder_region_style_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_row e5_ ON e3_.builder_region_id = e5_.builder_region_id AND (e5_.builder_row_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_block e6_ ON e5_.builder_row_id = e6_.builder_row_id AND (e6_.builder_block_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_block_attribute e7_ ON e6_.builder_block_id = e7_.builder_block_id AND (e7_.builder_block_attribute_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_column e8_ ON e6_.builder_block_id = e8_.builder_block_id AND (e8_.builder_column_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_column_style e9_ ON e8_.builder_column_id = e9_.builder_column_id AND (e9_.builder_column_style_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_column_attribute e10_ ON e8_.builder_column_id = e10_.builder_column_id AND (e10_.builder_column_attribute_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_column_conf e11_ ON e8_.builder_column_id = e11_.builder_column_id AND (e11_.builder_column_conf_delete_status = 0) AND (e11_.builder_column_conf_delete_status = 0)
    LEFT JOIN builder_column e12_ ON e8_.builder_column_id = e12_.parent_builder_column_id AND (e12_.builder_column_delete_status = 0)
WHERE
    e0_.delete_status = 0
AND
    e0_.product_id = xxxxx
AND
    e0_.id = xxxxx
ORDER BY
    e3_.builder_region_sort_order ASC,

    e5_.builder_row_sort_order ASC,

    e6_.builder_block_sort_order ASC,

    e8_.builder_column_sort_order ASC
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on what is going on here?

Here is the full explain:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,e0_,,const,PRIMARY,id,id_2,product_id,customer_id,delete_status,rbac_role_id,delete_status_2,PRIMARY,8,const,1,100,"Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,SIMPLE,e1_,,ref,id,id,5,const,const,3,100,Using where
1,SIMPLE,e2_,,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,8,const,1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e3_,,ref,delete,delete,5,const,const,4,100,Using where
1,SIMPLE,e4_,,ref,builder_region_id,builder_region_id,5,"my_db_name.e3_.builder_region_id,const',1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e5_,,ref,builder_block_id,builder_block_id,5,"my_db_name.e3_.builder_region_id,const",1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e6_,,ref,builder_region_id,builder_region_id,6,"my_db_name.e5_.builder_row_id,const",1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e7_,,ref,builder_block_id,builder_block_id,5,"my_db_name.e6_.builder_block_id,const",1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e8_,,ALL,builder_row_id,,,,8,100,Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1,SIMPLE,e9_,,ref,builder_column_id,builder_column_id,5,"my_db_name.e8_.builder_column_id,const',5,100,
1,SIMPLE,e10_,,ref,builder_column_id,builder_column_id,5,"my_db_name.e8_.builder_column_id,const",2,100,
1,SIMPLE,e11_,,ref,builder_column_id,builder_column_id,5,"my_db_name.e8_.builder_column_id,const",1,100,
1,SIMPLE,e12_,,ALL,child_col,,,,8,100,Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

I just realized I posted the wrong create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `builder_column` (
  `builder_column_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `builder_block_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `builder_column_type_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `builder_column_delete_status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `builder_column_sort_order` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `builder_column_create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `builder_column_modify_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `builder_ui_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `parent_builder_column_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `builder_column_flags` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`builder_column_id`),
  KEY `builder_row_id` (`builder_block_id`,`builder_column_delete_status`),
  KEY `child_col` (`parent_builder_column_id`,`builder_column_delete_status`)
) ENGINE=TokuDB AUTO_INCREMENT=901184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_SNAPPY;
```

UPDATE:
I have found that if I add:

```
FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (email_builder_row_id)
```

and

```
FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (child_col)
```

it will use the index and returns fast.

Comment: Please add the CREATE TABLE and the query command.

Comment: And do you also need the create tables from the other joined tables?

Comment: Ppl must know why sometimes index is not used.

Comment: Please edit this sort of information into the question; it allows you to include formatting, is much easier to read, and doesn't have a limit on how much you can include. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to suggest that your data model is seriously flawed! You have table numbers going from 0 - 12 and column numbers from 1 - 100. Any time names have numbers after them like that, it's indicative of a **big** problem. It looks like just one horrendous mess! Please post the results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <your_query_here>` Is the table you wanted to give the DDL for `builder_row` or `builder_column`? Can you remove the incorrect one please?

Comment: That is coming from a doctrine 2 query. It aliases everything.

Comment: I have remove the ddl for builder row.

Answer (score 0):

(OK, not yet a 'real' Answer, but here goes...)

I would be filthy rich if I had a bitcoin for every "Why is it not using my index" Questions that I have answered.  This forum is loaded with such; so is stackoverflow.com .

But, alas, there is no single Answer that fits all Questions.  So, I will stare at your case.  Ouch, I may not be able to answer yours since it involves Tokudb.  (I added a tag, so you might get more traffic.)

Which table is not using the index?  Where are the other `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`?  The Optimizer is free to rearrange the order of hitting the tables; this could be *part* of the problem.

Have you `ANALYZEd` the tables recently?  (I don't know how much this is needed in TokuDB.)

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` unless the 'right' table is really optional.  Switching to `JOIN` gives the Optimizer more options.

Let's see the `EXPLAIN` before *and* after the change in query plan.

Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `email`?  If so, why filter on `product_id` and `delete_status` if you have the `id`?